# Differential of an operator on a function space

Tags: functional-analysis, differential

Assume that $X=C^1([0,1],||\cdot||_{\infty})$ and let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(g)=\int_0^1tg^2(t)dt$. What is the differential $Df$?

Comment: What is $f(g+h) - f(g)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: 
We have $$f(g+h)-f(g)=2\int_0^1 tg(t)h(t)dt + f(h).$$ As $A(h):= 2\int_0^1 tg(t)h(t)dt$ is a linear function, I assume this would be the Differential $Df$ at the point $g$. One would still need to show that $\varphi(h)\cdot ||h|| := f(h)$ gives a function $\varphi$ which is continuous in $0$ with $\varphi(0)=0$.

Comment: $\lvert f(h)\rvert \leqslant \int_0^1 t \lvert h(t)\rvert^2\,dt \leqslant \int_0^1 t\cdot \lVert h\rVert_\infty^2\,dt$